# Extension methods not working for int?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    static string Format(this int integer) // Write one for int too, just incase :')
    {
        return string.Format("{0:n0}", integer);
    }
}
```

Calling the following code tells me the method `Format` doesn't exist.

```
idItemsFinished.Format()
```

Here is the variable

```
var idItemsFinished = Program.IdItemsProcessed;
```

It's simply just an int.

```
public int IdItemsProcessed;
```

Comment: All types already have a "format" sort of method called `ToString()`, i.e. you could simply use `idItemsFinished.ToString("n0")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a **public** access specifier to the extension method should fix the issue.

```
public static class NumberExtentions
{
    public static string Format(this int integer) 
    {
        return string.Format("{0:n0}", integer);
    }
}
```

[See Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RpmB8L)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the subject - yes, extension methods do work on `int`, there's nothing special about `int`. In fact, they'll work on integer literals as well - `5.Format()` should work fine.

You've left out what I suspect is the reason for your problem, which is namespaces. There might be dozens of places in your code and especially your dependent libraries that add extension methods to `int` and you don't want to necessarily import them all (leading to potential conflicts), so you have to add a `using` statement to your code that points to the namespace of `NumberExtentions`.

This is no different than adding a reference to a class, except that Visual Studio's intellisense is usually pretty good in highlighting an unknown class and offering to add a `using` for it for you, but it won't be as helpful with extension methods.

Simply add a using statement and you'll probably be good to go.